# Limit and offset in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need the solution for the following query in oracle

```
select * from option_list order by option_id LIMIT 4 OFFSET 1
```

facing following errror while execution

```
odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

kindly help me to get solution for offset and limit in oracle query execution with php

Note : in postgres query is working fine but problem is with oracle

Comment: Please spend 5-10 minutes searching Stack Overflow before you post a question.

Comment: `select * from (
select rownum as rnm,  ol.*  from option_list ol
)tm where tm.rnm>=1 and rnm<=10`

Answer (score -1):

> Here is your solution you have to make query structure like this

```
select * 
  from ( select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */ 
  a.*, ROWNUM rnum 
      from ( your_query_goes_here, 
      with order by ) a 
      where ROWNUM <= 
      :MAX_ROW_TO_FETCH ) 
where rnum  >= :MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH;
```

> for more details please [go to here](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-rownum-and-limiting-results)